# Apache Ant stuck while calling git pull

Tags: git, ant, hudson

In apache ant script I have macro:

```
<macrodef name = "git">
  <attribute name = "command" />
  <attribute name = "options" />
  <attribute name = "dir" default = "" />
  <attribute name="failonerror" default="false"/>
  <sequential>
    <echo message = "GIT Command: git @{command} @{options}, dir: @{dir}" />
    <exec executable = "C:\Git\cmd\git.exe" dir = "@{dir}">
      <arg value = "@{command}" />
      <arg value = "@{options}" />
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And later I am calling:

```
<git command = "pull" options = '-v' dir = "subfolder/subsubfolder" failonerror = "true"/>
```

But when I start my Hudson job with dir as `subfolder/subsubfolder` or `C:\direct\path\to\subfolder\subsubfolder\` my job just stuck on it and I get only echo in console output. Not even error or anything. Hudson is installed on machine with Windows XP.

I've tried to use this command in Windows CMD - it's working when I am at the repo folder like this:

```
C:\direct\path\to\subfolder\subsubfolder>C:\Git\cmd\git.exe pull -v
```

What am I doing wrong? There is way for better integration git with ant?

Some new notes:

- if I am trying to exec git pull in bad directory I get error.
- if I am trying to exec git checkout it works.
- if I am trying to exec git fetch it hangs like git pull.

Another EDIT, maybe some clues:
I change direct Git calling for a .bat file with git commands in it. It's simple some `CD` to get to the directory and then `git pull`. When I run script it's simply well working. But it hangs forever in Hudson. Maybe it's something with calling git subprocess in Java that needs some environment variables? Git is using SSH power-less connection without any agent in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it "hangs", there is probably an interactive prompt and Jenkins can't handle that.

Try adding `<arg line="> out.txt 2>&1"/>` to your `exec` at the end. This will redirect everything to a file, so that after it hangs again, kill the job, and review the contents of that file `out.txt`

Note that you will need to escape the `>` and `&`, so it will be:
`<arg line="&gt; out.txt 2&gt;&amp;1"/>`

Comment: I can't redirect output simply by the `> out 2>&1` - I get invalid refspec error. Ant Exec Task has `output` and `outputproperty` for redirecting output. But they return nothing, not even create a file.

Anyway - I am using power-less SSH connection with repository. And using commands in Windows CMD or GitBash do not need typing anything.

Comment: Jenkins uses it's own 'jenkins' user (on Windows, by default it uses 'Local System' user), which is different then your usual logged in user. If you are using password-less SSH, relying on keys in your user profile folder, that won't work for the jenkins session. You need to configure the SSH keys for jenkins user in particular, or better yet, don't rely on implied keys locations and instead specify the path to the keys. For `ssh` there is a `-i` option. Don't know about `git`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your advice help me a lot. As a temporary solution in Ant script I am calling PSExec which is calling batch script with git command in it. Weird, but working. I'm gonna to rewrite script in Gradle to simplify it.